# Ionic: How to get path file in www folder from created plugin

Tags: android, plugins, ionic-framework

I'm already created a plugin for my project and gratefully its work fine. Then I want to add another function on it that call an image in **www folder** (www/img/demo.png). I tried with this path

```
String picPath = "file://android/assets/www/img/demo.jpg";
```

But, it return with error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 String picPath = "file://android_asset/www/img/demo.jpg;
```

If you test on android device.

Comment: One more try: if($ionicPlatform.is('android')){String picPath = '/android_asset/www/img/demo.jpg;' }

Comment: Same error, I'm also tried with String picPath = "/android/assets/www/img/demo.jpg"; also got same error. I try again.